# Hittest not working properly when view is not the size of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitouch, hittest

Im trying to use `hitTest` inside a subclass of `UIView` to get which child Im hovering on.

```
class TestView:UIView {
    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let point = touches.anyObject()!.locationInView(self)

        print(point)
        print("\t\t\t")
//        println(self.hitTest(point, withEvent: event))
        println(self.layer.hitTest(point))
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let l1 = UILabel(text: "Hej 1")
        l1.frame.origin.y = 50
        l1.center.x = self.center.x

        let l2 = UILabel(text: "Hej 2")
        l2.frame.origin.y = 140
        l2.center.x = self.center.x

        self.addSubview(l1)
        self.addSubview(l2)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

// In viewDidLoad()
let view = TestView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.center = self.view.center
//view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

If you would kindly paste this into xcode and try it you can see whats happening much better than I can explain, but I'll give it a try anyways.

Ok, when using the `UIView hitTest` It ONLY returns the `TestView` and never its children.

When using the `CALayer hitTest` it seems like the coordinate scheme is to the bottom right of the screen. (This is the part when its better to check for yourselves because I have no idea whats going on and its hard to describe).

But when I change `view.frame = self.view.bounds` it works like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the view's hitTest method, you **need to set userInteractionEnabled to true** for your labels to register a hit.

```
println(self.hitTest(point, withEvent:nil)!) // this works if you enable interaction on the labels
```

I'm not sure what's going on with the layer method; I've never worked with that before.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something small and silly I was missing :)